# Add top rows of Data Frame from Numpy Array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I did the linear regression for filling NaN values on the historical data (extrapolate). So I have an array "predict" like this.

```
array([[75.30316986],
       [77.00583289],
       [75.77286072],
       [74.11922961]])
```

And i have a dataframe "y_wajak" like this :

```
   Date        ABJ
2014-03-01  89.928058
2014-04-01  85.765125
2014-05-01  85.512367
2014-06-01  86.730125
2014-07-01  87.947883
```

How can i make a dataframe so i have my data something like this?

```
   Date        ABJ
2013-11-01  75.30316986 (added top rows from array)
2013-12-01  77.00583289
2014-01-01  75.77286072
2014-02-01  74.11922961
2014-03-01  89.928058 (from "y_wajak" dataframe)
2014-04-01  85.765125
2014-05-01  85.512367
2014-06-01  86.730125
2014-07-01  87.947883
```

Can anyone help me? thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the append function. See [the documentation here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(y_wajak, pd.DataFrame(my_array))
```

You many need to add additional parameters to get the correct column names and types. But this should get you there.